# Reversible iterator

Tags: java, collections, iterator, listiterator

public ReversibleIterator iterator();

can anyone help me make this method? ill put up what i have done so far

The ReversibleIterator should behave as follows. The first call to next or previous should return the first or last element of the list, respectively. Subsequent calls to next/previous should return the element that is next/previous with respect to the antecedent call to next/previous. For example, if two calls to next result in Sunday and Monday, then a following call to previous should return Sunday.

```
public ReversibleIterator<T> iterator() {
    PublicLinkedList<T> list = new PublicLinkedList<T>();
    PublicNode<T> node = list.head;
    while (node.getElement() != null) {
        list.add(node.getElement());
        node = node.getNext();
    }
    ReversibleIterator<T> rIter = new ReversibleIterator<T>(list);
    return rIter;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at ListIterator which can be interated forward and backward?

Comment: Also note that in your example, the internal PublicLinkedList is always empty (unless the default constructor does something very unexpected underneath.) Did you indent for it to be a parameter? Member variable?

Answer (score 4):

Java's [ListIterator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) is what you need. The big advantage: It already exists.

You can retrieve it from any list in Java by calling the [listIterator()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#listIterator%28%29) function.